# Render multilple vtkpolydata contours

Tags: 3d, vtk

I am trying to make a 3D model of some contours.

For that I am using vtkAppendFilter, to append vtkPolyData ( which are my contours).
Then get the output in a new vtkPolyData instance.

I put in a mapper, then an actor ... and so on . But for some reason,

when I render it , I do not see anything. Just a black screen.

If someone know where I am wrong . Please let me know.

Thank you.

Here 's the code :

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData> appendFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData>::New();
double z=0;
//Does the job to append them
for(int i=0; i < this->mAllContoursRepresentations.size();i++){
    for(int j=0; j< this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).size();j++){
        // z. is the number of the image
        z = this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).at(j).first;
        //contour to copy
        vtkPolyData* pld = this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).at(j).second->GetContourRepresentationAsPolyData();
        //contour to paste
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> vtp = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
        //copy contour and paste it in another one
        vtp->DeepCopy(pld);
        vtkPoints* vtpPoints = vtp->GetPoints();
        vtkPoints* pldPoints = pld->GetPoints();
        vtpPoints->SetNumberOfPoints(pld->GetNumberOfPoints());
        for(int k=0;k<vtp->GetNumberOfPoints();k++){
            double toPixel[3];
            double points[3];
            pldPoints->GetPoint(k,points);
            vtkInteractorObserver::ComputeWorldToDisplay(Activity::GetActivity().GetDefaultRendererVisit(),points[0],points[1],points[2],toPixel);
            points[2]= z;
            points[1]=toPixel[1];
            points[0]=toPixel[0];
            vtpPoints->SetPoint(k,points);
        }
        //append contour to the filter
        appendFilter->AddInputData(vtp);
    }
}
appendFilter->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> contoursMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
contoursMapper->SetInputData(contours);
contoursMapper->ScalarVisibilityOff();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> contoursActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
contoursActor->SetMapper(contoursMapper);
contoursActor->GetProperty()->SetRepresentationToWireframe();
contoursActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1,0,1);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkVRMLExporter> exporter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVRMLExporter>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderer->AddActor(contoursActor);
renderer->ResetCamera();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
interactor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);  
renderWindow->Render();
exporter->SetFileName("C:\\Users\\stagiaire\\Desktop\\toto.wrl");
exporter->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
exporter->Write();
interactor->Initialize();
interactor->Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Google , I found a way to help my self.

Basically what I am doing is storing my points 
in a vector in order to build a new vtkpolydata structure (which is a contour -> simples lines)  and append it in the vtkAppendPolyData.Then using usuals instructions, I render it.

Here is the code, if someone need help (feel free to ask):

```
for(int i=0; i < this->mAllContoursRepresentations.size();i++){
        for(int j=0; j< this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).size();j++){
            //contour to copy
            vtkPolyData* pld = this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).at(j).second->GetContourRepresentationAsPolyData();

            // z. is the number of the image
            z = this->mAllContoursRepresentations.at(i).at(j).first;

            vtkPoints* pldPoints = pld->GetPoints();
            int numberPoints= pld->GetNumberOfPoints();

            for(int k=0;k<numberPoints;k++){
                pldPoints->GetPoint(k,toWorld);

                vtkInteractorObserver::ComputeWorldToDisplay(Activity::GetActivity().GetDefaultRendererVisit(),
                    toWorld[0],toWorld[1],toWorld[2],toPixel);


                qDebug()<< "Points Of contours - Image ";
                qDebug() << z;
                qDebug() << "\n";
                qDebug() << toPixel[0]; 
                qDebug() << toPixel[1];
                qDebug() << z;

                double *pointToSave =new double[3];
                pointToSave[0] =  toPixel[0];
                pointToSave[1] =  toPixel[1];
                pointToSave[2] =  z;

                pointsContours.push_back(pointToSave);  
            }
            pld = NULL;
            pldPoints= NULL;
        }

    }


    delete[] toPixel;
    delete[] toWorld;
    this->Stop();

    //create vtkAppendsPolyData in order to append contours together
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData> appendFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendPolyData>::New();
    int idPoint;
    idPoint=0;
    while(idPoint < pointsContours.size()){

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
        unsigned int k=0;       
        for(;idPoint < pointsContours.size()-1;idPoint++){
            if(pointsContours.at(idPoint)[2]==pointsContours.at(idPoint+1)[2]){
                points->InsertNextPoint(pointsContours.at(idPoint));
                k++;                                    
            }
            else 
                break;
        } 

        if(idPoint < pointsContours.size()){
            points->InsertNextPoint(pointsContours.at(idPoint));
            k++;            
            idPoint++;      
        }


        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine> polyline = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine>::New();
        polyline->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(k);
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<k;j++)
            polyline->GetPointIds()->SetId(j,j);

        // Create a cell array to store the lines in and add the lines to it
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> cells = 
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
        cells->InsertNextCell(polyline);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData = 
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

        // Add the points to the dataset
        polyData->SetPoints(points);

        // Add the lines to the dataset
        polyData->SetLines(cells);  

        appendFilter->AddInputData(polyData);
    }

    pointsContours.clear();
    appendFilter->Update();


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> contoursMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

    contoursMapper->SetInputData(appendFilter->GetOutput());
    contoursMapper->ScalarVisibilityOff();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> contoursActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    contoursActor->SetMapper(contoursMapper);
    contoursActor->GetProperty()->SetRepresentationToWireframe();
    contoursActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0,0,0);


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkVRMLExporter> exporter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVRMLExporter>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();


    renderer->AddActor(contoursActor);
    renderer->ResetCamera();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderer->SetBackground(1,1,1); // Background color
    interactor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
    interactor->Initialize();   
    renderWindow->Render();
    interactor->Start();
```

This example might help you too .
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/PolyLine